# java.io.file is turning // into /?

Tags: java, file, ftp

I'd like to instantiate a file from an FTP path like:

```
java.io.File file = new File("ftp://"+"path/to/file");
```

But when I try to get the fileInputStream of this file:

```
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
```

I get a java.io.FileNotFoundException.

When I debug, I can see that during the instantiation of the file object, the path turns to **"ftp:/path/to/file" --  with ONE slash** ==> which throws the exception since he needs double slashes "//" after "ftp:" to locate the file into the FTP server.

How can I make the path contain double slashes ?

Thank you

Comment: You are providing a URL, not a file path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a FTP client, such as [Apache Commons Net](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/).

The File API available in the JDK cannot connect to a FTP server out of the box.